# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}(ax)!/x^x$ in terms of $a$

Tags: exponential-function, factorial

This is my first post here, so I hope the question is formatted correctly.
Anyway, like the title says, I was wondering if there exists any real (or complex) value of $a$ such that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(ax)!}{x^x} =1$$

I have tried looking for a solution graphically, but I wasn't able to find anything useful.

Comment: Please add what $(ax)!$ is supposed to mean, if $ax$ is not an integer. Maybe the Gamma function? Are you aware of Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 2):

Stirling gives $(ax)! \sim \sqrt{2\pi ax}\left(\frac{ax}{e}\right)^{ax}$, so the answer is no. For $a = 1$ it converges to $0$ and for $a > 1$ it diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Can you please write a "formal" proof of why it behaves like that? I'd really appreciate it :)